# Avoid Race condition in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form which returns data logs on submit button.To display the logs I implemented infinite scroll. Whenever the scroll bar reaches the bottom of the page the next set of logs get loaded as an ajax call gets fired. However sometimes the logs do not appear in right order and sometimes multiple calls are triggered. How can I prevent that?

My code:

```
function infinite_scroll(data){
$.ajax({
    url: '/api',
    dataType: 'json',
    data : data,
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    success: function(response) {
                $('#table_body').append(" some data ");
    },
    error: function( xhr, status ) {
    alert( "Sorry, there was a problem! Please Try Again!" );
    },
  });
}
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if($(window).scrollTop() +$(window).height()==$(document).height()) {
           infinite_scroll(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because the `infinite_scroll` function gets called for every single pixel that the UI can render as the user scrolls down. That's potentially thousands of AJAX requests in a very short space of time, and all of them racing each other - as you've found.

A solution to this is to 'debounce' the scroll event so that the function is only called after scrolling has stopped. In your case this will ensure that an AJAX request is sent only on the last position of the scroll handle. This will stop the race condition and also dramatically reduce the load on your server. Try this:

```
var scrollTimer;

$(window).scroll(function () {
    clearTimeout(scrollTimer);
    scrollTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
           infinite_scroll(data);
        }
    }, 200); // 200ms delay
});
```

You should also remove `async: false` from your AJAX request as it's incredibly bad practice to use.

Comment: Beyond being bad practice `async: false` is also deprecated by browsers and now throws warnings in console

Comment: @charlietfl I'm more surprised the scrolling worked without the UI jumping all over the place

Comment: Me too actually. Would have thought that the blocking would prevent further scrolling

Comment: @Rory, that's probably because `async: false` prevents the requests from actually running in parallel.

Comment: True, but I would have through the UI would have hung while scrolling when the request is processing.